# using crypto library looks like cipher update is not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, encryption, cryptojs

i have crypto module to do string encryption when passed string is not 16 bytes i assume cipher.update() should do some padding and create 16 bytes string but that is not happening while debugging cipher.update returns empty string, is there other way to do padding using crypto.

index.js

```
function paymentIdencryption(text)

        const secret_key = "EiE0BVQle0xFjZvYOupKjFGHAcAwBaTjlZ7G7rryNos=";
        const secretKeyWordArray = CCrypto.enc.Utf8.parse(secret_key);

        const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', Buffer.from(secret_key, 'base64'), iv);
        let encrypted = cipher.update(JSON.stringify(text), 'utf8', 'base64');
        encrypted += cipher.final('base64');
        const encryptedData = { iv: iv.toString('base64'), encrypted: encodeURIComponent(encrypted)};
       return encryptedData.encrypted;
}

console.log(paymentIdencryption("1384220_8089105");
```

Expected Result key Size :

GwJPNUfPXZZsuc0iqOFhn%2BYhMJKxXBUGl9g3iKqL8CE%3D

But it returns : jJtKhwjqS5N4ABIrZev8Ng%3D%3D

Java Code that does decryption

```
var imp = new JavaImporter(com.vordel.mime,org.json.simple.JSONObject,com.vordel.trace);
 
with(imp) {
function invoke(msg)         {            
 
var encodedKey = "${env.SPL.paymentMethodId.key}";
Trace.info ("env.SPL.paymentMethodId.key -- encodedKey  = " + encodedKey); 
var encodedPaymentInfo= msg.get("cvs.paymentMethodId");
 
var encryptedPaymentInfo = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(encodedPaymentInfo,"UTF-8");

var decodedKey = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedKey.getBytes("UTF-8"));
var decodedcipher = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedPaymentInfo.getBytes("UTF-8"));

 
var cipher = javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"); 
var secretKey = new javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, "AES"); 
var iv = new javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec(decodedcipher,0,16);
cipher.init(javax.crypto.Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,secretKey,iv);
 
var decryptedPaymentInfo = cipher.doFinal(decodedcipher, 16, decodedcipher.length-16);
var paymentInfo = new java.lang.String(decryptedPaymentInfo,"UTF-8"); 
var patientId = paymentInfo.substring(paymentInfo.indexOf("_")+1, paymentInfo.length());
var paymentId = paymentInfo.substring(0, paymentInfo.indexOf("_"));
 
msg.put("cvs.spl.patientId",patientId);
msg.put("cvs.spl.paymentId",paymentId);
 
return true;         
 
}
};
```

Comment: *...is not working as expected?...* Why do you expect a 32 bytes ciphertext with a 15 bytes plaintext? Note that your code already pads your plaintext to 16 bytes with PKCS#7. If the IV is concatenated with the ciphertext (which is common practice) the result is 32 bytes, maybe that's what you mean. But there are also other possible reasons for a 32 bytes ciphertext. Are you trying to migrate a code? If so, please post this code.

Comment: @NotARobot with above code its not working as expected i am trying to get 32 bytes output which only happen when plaintText is 16 bytes my passed string is 15 bytes that i am expecting cipher.update to add some padding and make it 16

Comment: You seem to believe that there is only one way to turn 15 bytes plaintext into a 32 bytes ciphertext. But that's not the case. There are many ways to achieve this: Put the IV in front (see above), format the plaintext (e.g. leading blank), modify the PKCS#7 padding so that it does not pad to multiples of 16 but to 32 bytes etc. etc. You have to specify the encryption logic somehow (via a document or a reference code).

Comment: @NotARobot thanks for sharing details can you please share some options what you mean by leading blank or how to modify padding , this is first time i am implementing in Nodejs so i dont have any other reference to share if i pass this it works "1384220__8089105" extra special character but i know this is not right way to do thats why want padding to be done using crypto padding PKCS#7

Comment: Obviously you have more information that for some reason you don't want to share. How else would you know that `1384220__8089105` is not the right way to go? It is unclear to me why you are asking questions here but are unwilling to provide the required context or information to answer them. Please have a look at [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and try to revise your question so that it is suitable for SO.

Comment: @NotARobot i have added the java code that does the decryption if this helps

Comment: And the hint about the IV wasn't enough for you? Oh dear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java code performs a URL decoding of the encrypted data, followed by a Base64 decoding. The first 16 bytes of the result are used as IV, the rest as ciphertext.
The key is Base64 decoded.
With key and IV, the ciphertext is now decrypted with AES in CBC mode and PKCS#7 padding.
The decrypted data is decoded with UTF-8.
The `patientid` (the data after the `_`) and the `paymentid` (the data before the `_`) are extracted from the resulting string.

From this, the logic for the encryption can be determined:

- Base64 decoding of the key
- generation of a random 16 bytes IV
- encryption with aes-256-cbc (AES-256 because of the 32 bytes key) using key and IV
- concatenation of IV and ciphertext
- Base64 encoding of the ciphertext with subsequent URL encoding

##### Possible NodeJS implementation:

```js
var crypto = require('crypto')
function paymentIdencryption(text) {
    const secret_key = "EiE0BVQle0xFjZvYOupKjFGHAcAwBaTjlZ7G7rryNos=";
    const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', Buffer.from(secret_key, 'base64'), iv);
    const encrypted = Buffer.concat([iv, cipher.update(text, 'utf8'), cipher.final()]);
    return encodeURIComponent(encrypted.toString('base64'))
}
console.log(paymentIdencryption("1384220_8089105"));
```

Possible output (changes for each encryption because of the random IV):

```
5I43wWYs84XQk9Pe0IMl4g%2B7s%2BgwcJrPsWo9gcX25y8%3D
```

##### Test with the Java code:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        var encodedPaymentInfo = "5I43wWYs84XQk9Pe0IMl4g%2B7s%2BgwcJrPsWo9gcX25y8%3D"; 
        var encodedKey = "EiE0BVQle0xFjZvYOupKjFGHAcAwBaTjlZ7G7rryNos=";
        
        var encryptedPaymentInfo = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(encodedPaymentInfo,"UTF-8");

        var decodedKey = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedKey.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        var decodedcipher = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedPaymentInfo.getBytes("UTF-8"));
         
        var cipher = javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"); 
        var secretKey = new javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, "AES"); 
        var iv = new javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec(decodedcipher,0,16);
        cipher.init(javax.crypto.Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,secretKey,iv);
         
        var decryptedPaymentInfo = cipher.doFinal(decodedcipher, 16, decodedcipher.length-16);
        var paymentInfo = new java.lang.String(decryptedPaymentInfo,"UTF-8"); 
        var patientId = paymentInfo.substring(paymentInfo.indexOf("_")+1, paymentInfo.length());
        var paymentId = paymentInfo.substring(0, paymentInfo.indexOf("_"));
         
        System.out.println("cvs.spl.patientId: " + patientId);
        System.out.println("cvs.spl.paymentId: " + paymentId);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
cvs.spl.patientId: 8089105
cvs.spl.paymentId: 1384220
```

which is equal to the data of the original plaintext.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, i think that was the issue need to encode and concat including iv.